# Typescript share function overload

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function with multiple overloads. Is there any way to "share" the same overloads in a different function?

```
function getEmployee(id: number): Employee;
function getEmployee(email: string): Employee;
function getEmployee(email: number, name: string): Employee;
function getEmployee (paramOne: string | number, paramTwo?: string ): Employee { 
  return employee;
}
```

If I want to use the same overloads in other functions, I need to copy all of them manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share types you can do something like this:

```
interface GetEmployeeFunctionType {
    (id: number): Employee;
    (email: string): Employee;
    (email: number, name: string): Employee;
    (paramOne: string | number, paramTwo?: string): Employee;
}
```

And then your new function just type it like so:

```
const newFunction: GetEmployeeFunctionType = (/** your parameters */) => {// implementation}
```

When you call newFunction it will give you correct intelisense.

Comment: I want to use it in a class's method

Comment: if you want to use it as a class method you can do this:

class SomeClass {
    public test: GetEmployeeFunctionType = () => {
        // implementation

    }
}

Comment: and it'll not be on the prototype. Not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Kaca992 answer, I believe it should be altered in a way, since the last signature is not an overload signature but an implementation signature.

```
interface GetEmployeeFunctionType {
    (id: number): Employee;
    (email: string): Employee;
    (email: number, name: string): Employee;
}

const newFunction: GetEmployeeFunctionType = (paramOne: string | number, paramTwo?: string): Employee => {/* implementation */}
```

On the other hand, you can always create a higher order function to wrap the signatures:

```
interface GetEmployeeFunctionType {
    (id: number): Employee;
    (email: string): Employee;
    (email: number, name: string): Employee;
}

function wrap(func: (paramOne: string | number, paramTwo?: string) => Employee): GetEmployeeFunctionType {
    return func;
}

// usage:
const f = wrap((arg1, arg2) => {/* implementation */});
```

See [TypeScript Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=54&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOAbA9gTwhQG8BYAKGSuTgC5kBnMKUAcwG4KBfCi0SWIhQBxCGAw4CRAGIBXEAjDBcIACr5MJCtWQAKYABN6IWegBG0AJT0JeQhE6VquiOjjBs9JixCtraLDsiRx0XNw9jUwsoABpkEDh0CC9mNn9bKQduXnIYeUVlEGQAdyg4TF08hXpdTDgy9AB5EGTGVN9kAB94qOg4uobVYtwAfhSfP2QAXgA%20AMl7f1FxQMy5BSUVdU1kMicqKDFZKCKqhEcecgoEFSZkGGmSsordetYARji3gCZLabniMhDmBjkVAXRkABySHILiwyzsIA) for that

Comment: I want to use it in a class's method

Comment: In what way? Can't you just do `class A { public method = wrap(/* func */); }` ?

Comment: In the normal way: method() { }

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't work... :/ I removed it. Not sure if that's possible this way

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2020, syntax for this case is *not currently available*. There are relevant issues in the TypeScript issue tracker:

- #22063: ["Suggestion: Type annotations and interfaces for function declarations"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) (Feb 2018)
- #34319: ["Describe function signature using an interface"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34319) (Oct 2019)
- #37433: ["Add mechanism for specifying the type of a function declaration"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37433) (Mar 2020, closed as dupe of #22063)

Though there are workarounds using interfaces and call signatures as in [Kaca992's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091597/1426891), they do not result in the same method structure as the syntax you requested (and that is proposed in those issues).