# How do you add an interface to a regular function in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, interface

So I'm rather new to typescript but I'm loving it a lot. I do have a question though.

Consider the following:

```
interface ResourceGetter<TInput, TOutput> {
  (id: TInput): TOutput;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const getUser: ResourceGetter<number, User> = (id: number): User => {
  return { id, name: 'Some random person' };
}
```

So the above example is valid typescript. But why do I have to use an arrow function if I want to apply an interface to my function? Why cant I do:

```
function getUser<ResourceGetter<number, User>>(id: number): User {
  // some code here.
}
```

Apparently this isn't valid typescript :/

Can someone show me an example of applying an interface to a normal function? Not a function stored in a variable (let func = function() {}).. a normal function.

Comment: For the TypeScript feature request, see [#22063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063), among [the other links in my overload answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61809404/1426891).

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply an explicit type to a function statement (meaning `function fnName(...args) {...body}`). There just is no syntax for that.

You can type the the arguments, and the return value, but not the whole function as one type.

Which means the closes you will get is this:

```
function getUser(
  id: Parameters<ResourceGetter<number, User>>
): ReturnType<ResourceGetter<number, User>> {
  // some code here.
}
```

[Working example of that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4HsCuUkDiEYkUAPACoCSIADjmADTIUDyD9YAfMgN4BQyZAApgAEwBcLGpwCUUthwYBufgF9+-UKXhJkAVQzQ+g5OKkgcAWwBG0VUJBwrEKRjBRQAc1Ub+MHBAEMGAsEGQvYkNoUUlkAAU4KGdiaAwydGw8QmJSMktbaGZoqC4ueTRiPBAKAE9aCAzMXHwIIhJofOs7KGKjUp4BISgqqHDeNWQ4DCmQWuQAegXkBCwxFAALaAh1IA)

---

This isn't really a big deal in practice. If you assign that function to a something that expects a certain function type, it still validates that everything is right.